# arules/ as/ how to import a coercion method to another package?

Tags: r, arules

I would like to use package arules functionalities in my package but can not
import the whole package due to name conflicts. object@datafr is a data frame that needs to be coerced to transactions. How should I deal with the second line in the code below?

```
showrules <- function(object, support=0.05, confidence=0.5){
combinations <- as(object@datafr, "transactions")
rules <- arules::apriori(combinations, parameter = list(support = support,          
confidence = confidence), appearance=list(rhs='target=high', default='lhs'))
arules::inspect(rules)
}
```

Comment: Can you share what in the namespace conflict is bothering you?

Comment: It was 'predict' from 'stats', which I imported as it is rather than used it as  stats::predict

Comment: Strange. arules imports predict from stats and exports a new S4 method for predict. However, that should not mask other predict methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to call `as()` using a namespace qualifier (`arules::coerce()` does not work), but luckily `apriori()` accepts also data.frames and coerces them internally into transactions. So you can just use:

`rules <- arules::apriori(object@datafr, parameter= list(support = support, confidence = confidence), appearance=list(rhs='target=high', default='lhs'))`